# How display longitude and latitude on labels-swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to display the longitude and latitude on 2 labels named longitude and latitude but I'm not having any results.

```
import UIKit
    import CoreLocation
    class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var longitude: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var latitude: UILabel!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
                        locationManager.delegate = self
                        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                    } else {
                        println("Location services are not enabled");
                    }
                }
        // MARK: - CoreLocation Delegate Methods
            func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
                locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                removeLoadingView()
                if ((error) != nil) {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
                var locationArray = locations as NSArray
                var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as CLLocation
                var coord = locationObj.coordinate
                longitude.text = coord.longitude
                latitude.text = coord.latitude

            }
    }
```

I'm having errors on longitude.text =coord.logitude and same for the second table it says it can't convert to string. I'm new to Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You convert the numbers to strings, such as with:

```
longitude.text = "\(coord.longitude)"
```